# Почему в WooCommerce могут не отображаться способы оплаты?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, интернет-магазин

Суть вопроса в заголовке. Далее подробно:
Подключил к интернет-магазину на WooCommerce платёжную систему "Альфа-Банка". Активировал её в настройка WooCommerce (*WooCommerce > Настройки > Платежи > Параметры оформления заказов (первая вкладка)*), перешёл к оформлению заказа и вижу что мне не показывается способ оплаты, не смотря на то что он 1, он всё равно должен быть показан. Я вернулся всё в то же меню настроек и включил ещё несколько способов оплаты и обнаружил что они так же не отображаются и выбрать я их не могу. До этого я уже включал платёжную систему и всё работало. Но на какое-то время я её отключал и ей не занимался. А занимался способами доставки. Что может влиять на отображение выбора способа оплаты при оформлении заказа? Подскажите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Вопрос уровня профессиональных ведунов и телепатов. Опишите конкретные задачи, что предприняли, какие флаги стоят, какие шаблоны что выводят.

Comment: Буду вам благодарен, если вы обратите внимания на другой мой вопрос. Чуть более сложный. Надеюсь что там я более конкретно описал задачу и своё видение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался с проблемой когда подробно вам хотел описать что я делал. Оказывается, когда я пытался использовать для покупки тестовый товар стоимостью 0 рублей, способ оплаты не выводятся)) спасибо вам в любом случае за ответ!